# Using ODEs in projectile motion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics, projectile-motion

If a cannon fires a cannon ball, where the only other forces are gravity and friction (denoted $pv$, where $v$ is velocity and $p$ is a constant), what would the horizontal 
equation be in terms of ODEs? Would I be right in assuming $m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+c\frac{dx}{dt}=0$?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: make the ansatz $$x(t)=e^{\lambda t}$$ and plug this in your equation

Comment: Thanks, i wasn't so much asking how to solve it, rather clarification that I have derived the correct ODE before proceeding? :)

Comment: Google for the right equation!

Comment: Google didn't seem to be very clear